# How to populate information from a list into multiple JSON objects using python?

Tags: python, json, list, file, object

Essentially have a list of JSON objects called `subfolders` which needs to hold information from 2 files -- 1 from a list called `json_files` and the other stored in a list called `table_files`.

The information from `json_files` and `table_files` needs to be included one time each in order within each JSON object.

So far, I'm able to output both my list of JSON objects and the information that is to be held within those objects separately, but cannot do it together in the format that I need, which is the problem.

My code for outputting the `subfolders` list:

```
subfolders = [ f.path for f in os.scandir(rootdir) if f.is_dir() ]
subfolders = [sub.replace(rootdir + '\\', '') for sub in subfolders]

obj = { conf_name:{} for conf_name in subfolders }

with open('summary.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(obj, f, indent=2)
```

My code for outputting the `json_data` and `table_data` information that is to be stored within the subfolders:

```
json_data = []
for i in json_files:
    with open(i) as f:
        json_data.append(json.load(f))

table_data = []
for i in table_files:
    with open(i) as f:
        table_data.append([line.rstrip('\n') for line in f])

combined = []
for j, t in zip(json_data, table_data):
    combined.append(j)
    combined.extend(t)

with open('summary.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(combined, f, indent=2)
```

Desired output:

```
{
   "subfolder1": {
      "json_data": "{content from first json_data file in list}"
      "table_data": "content from first table_data file in list"
   },
   "subfolder2": {
      "json_data": "{content from second json_data file in list}"
      "table_data": "content from second json_data file in list"
   }
}
```

Thus, I'm wondering how I can combine everything together to produce the format that I need. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: for getting the list of `json_files` and `table_files`:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".json"):
            json_files.append(os.path.join(subdir, file))
        if file.endswith(".list"):
            table_files.append(os.path.join(subdir, file))
```

Comment: how do you get the `json_files` and `table_files`

Comment: Edited my original post. Basically go through the subdirectory and append them to a list based on the suffix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try the following:

```
summary = {}
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".json"):
            json_files.append(os.path.join(subdir, file))
        if file.endswith(".list"):
            table_files.append(os.path.join(subdir, file))

    json_data = []
    for i in json_files:
        with open(i) as f:
            json_data.append(json.load(f))

    table_data = []
    for i in table_files:
        with open(i) as f:
            table_data.append([line.rstrip('\n') for line in f])

    summary[subdir] = {
        'json_data': json_data,
        'table_data': table_data
    }
with open('summary.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(summary, f, indent=2)
```

Comment: Actually a small error in this - instead of only populating 1 ```json_data``` and 1 ```table_data``` file's information at a time, this populates the whole list at once for each JSON object. If you can edit the answer to reflect this and have it as 1 file each at a time, that'd be great, thanks

Comment: inside a subdir will there be multiple json files, if yes how do you want the desired output

Comment: In each subdir, there should be 1 JSON file and 1 .list file. The output should be the same with the information from 1 JSON file and 1 .list file within each object

Comment: Please explain your answer.